# SQL Server displays char(1) as 4 characters wide, padded by spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I've been constructing a simple query to return fixed width records for export to an older application. I've used

```
Select Cast([myColumn1] as char(1)), Cast([myColumn2] as char(1)) from myTable
```

for single character columns, but the displayed result in SQL Server Management Studio always pads it out to 4 characters. For example, for a couple of single-character columns, it displays:

```
---- ----
P    A
```

I would expect to see:

```
- -
P A
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. Will this still occur if I use the query in code or will it format as expected with single character width? What I'm wondering is if it is a feature of the output pane in SSMS (although it exhibits the same behaviour when output to a file).
2. If it does occur, is there a workaround?

I hope that's not a dumb question, but can't seem to find any documentation...

Comment: What result? From "Results to Grid", or "to Text", or what? If this occurs in all contexts, (A) that's bizarre and (B) I wonder if using `left()` instead changes things.

Comment: It's in grid, text and file! I tried the left(mycolumn, 1) too with the same results...

Comment: What if you do `select 'a' from myTable`?

Comment: ----
    a

    (1 row affected) - same result

Comment: @PeterHolloway What is your problem exactly, please try to post a sample data and desired outputs.

Comment: @Sami I've edited the question to include expected output.

Comment: Seems like you're having displaying problems, not data type problems.

Comment: What does `SELECT LEN(CAST('a' AS char(1))) ` return you - 1, or 4?

Comment: I can't duplicate this. Going to vote to close soon unless anyone can reproduce it. Created a table (SQL Server 2014) with char(4) columns. Populated with single characters. Cast as char(1). Result is 1 character.

Comment: @CaiusJard it returns 1, which is expected, but strangely SSMS chooses to display that result an 11 character string... very curious

Comment: We had assumed that you had tried outputting the data somewhere and determined that it was really 4 characters wide, not just *displayed* as that!

Comment: @JacobH just because you can't reproduce it doesn't mean it's not happening. I'd like to get to the bottom of it. Is it an SSMS display issue or something more fundamental? (Using SSMS 17.3)

Comment: @underscore_d - I did mention that it's an output from SSMS in the question - apologies if it was ambiguous

Comment: @PeterHolloway https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm actually going to upvote this since it reflects a quirk of SSMS's display routines that I find it difficult to find other relevant info about on a quick search.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks, I do think it's a verifiable issue, apologies again if the question was not as clear as it could have been, but it was genuine, and there is a 'quirk' to remember ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underscores have no bearing on the actual data. 4 is the minimum number SSMS will display.

Try this and verify:

```
DECLARE @varA VARCHAR(4) = 'A'
,@varB VARCHAR(4) = 'B'
SELECT '|'+CAST(@varA AS CHAR(1))+'|'+@varB
```

Comment: Thanks @digital.aaron That clarifies - so I can't use SSMS for testing fixed width output with columns under 4 characters.

Comment: Why wouldn't you test fixed width output by creating a fixed width flat file instead?

Comment: I have a large number of fields and wanted to get the query right before outputting to a file. I thought it would be simple to copy the output from the SSMS results pane to compare with an existing file and then code the output once I was sure it was correct. I wasn't aware of this feature of SSMS or I would have gone straight to the file...

Comment: Is this documented anywhere that you know of, or is it just known through trial-and-error?

Comment: Viewing query results in SSMS is a bit inconsistent. I wouldn't use SSMS results window for anything mission critical.

Comment: @underscore_d, not anywhere that I know of. It was, however, brought up in a side conversation in a Kimberley Tripp SQL Server training course I attended many years ago.

Comment: @digital.aaron I wasn't planning on using it for mission critical, I just wanted to see it look right before coding it up. I thought it would make development easier if I could copy and paste query results until my output matched the expected fixed width file. I guess I'll have to go write a bit of code to write to a file ;)

Comment: Or have your query concat the data into the lines: don't select 20 char(1) columns in the hopes of getting a string 20 chars long out.. CONCAT(20 char(1)), and then you'll get a 20-long string out. Put it into grid mode too, not textbox mode, and copy out of the grid

Answer (score 2):

for Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio you can change the output format in - Tools-> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results To Text.

[Options Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELVBu.png)

If you are using Column aligned for the Output format it will display with ---- and increase depending on the data type, however it doesn't have to match the data type actual length, e.g. data of size 1 will display with 4 ----.

You can test this with the following:

```
select 'a',  CAST(1 AS INT), CAST(1 AS BIGINT)
```

To validate the data actual length you can use DATALENGTH - documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql).

Comment: Thanks Blurr, it's the first time I've used this combination of a single character column and fixed width output. At least now I know not to trust the output pane to be a true representation of the result of the query in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to summarise what it was I was actually trying to find. See copied comments below.

There is a known feature of the SSMS results pane that it will not return less than 4 characters for any column. This is not documented, but is a consistent and verifiable feature. This means that the results pane is not suitable for testing queries that rely on specific formatting or the width of the returned column.

```
Is this documented anywhere that you know of, or is it just known through 
trial-and-error? – underscore_d 17 hours ago

Viewing query results in SSMS is a bit inconsistent. I wouldn't use SSMS 
results window for anything mission critical. – digital.aaron 17 hours ago

@underscore_d, not anywhere that I know of. It was, however, brought up in a 
side conversation in a Kimberley Tripp SQL Server training course I attended 
many years ago. – digital.aaron 17 hours ago
```